# Using Ion with an Application Context

Tags: android, android-ion, ion-koush

I'm interested in using Ion/AndroidAsync for the "backend" of an Android app. I don't want to make long running calls tied to an Android component, so I have a background layer that stays alive as long as the `Application` is alive. This background layer has an API that allows the UI to make async calls to perform different tasks, and returns a `Future` to the UI (also allows for a callback that gets executed on the main thread) so that it can be passed between components if need be.

I like Ion's API, but don't want to call it from an Activity; rather, I'd like to use it in my background layer, since a "task" may also need to do other long running operations in conjunction with a network call. That being said, will I run into any issues if I pass an application `Context` to `Ion.with()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work fine with an Application Context. It will never cancel any requests, as the Application context never dies. But that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. My project is using Ion default instance with Application context request for  all images.
2. http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.koushikdutta.ion.loader.HttpLoader
   this open source example use a context to get the application context. so , you can use applciation  as well.
3. But Ion instance  has the  Application reference,I think the long task may cause the application instance leaks .
4. Ion.getDefault(Context context).cancelAll(Object o);  It's mananger your request task better for you application.